# adding dynamic message at end of flash video

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, flash

I am working on a Flash training video.  I would like at the end of the video for a message to pop up with a dynamic confirmation code.  I have the code for the confirmation code, but am having trouble creating something either at the end of the flash video or within the aspx page to  trigger this message.  Any thoughts or ideas of how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using URLLoader to get the confirmation code from the ASP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on the purpose of the application, you can do either one. One thing to consider is does the user has to go through the flash video to obtain the *code*. If so, you need to organize the **flow** of the application in a way that the user can't cheat their way to obtain the code.

The ideal way is to have the **flash** called aspx page at the end of the movie to obtain the dynamic code. This can be done using `URLLoader` in ActionScript 3.0 or `LoadVars` in ActionScript 2.0.

`URLLoader` **example**

```
//this is the data
var data = "This is data";
//url of your aspx code
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.yourdomain.com/GenerateCode.aspx");
request.contentType = "text/xml";
request.data = data;
//use POST method
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
try
{
    //execute the request
    loader.load(request);
}
catch (error:ArgumentError)
{
    trace("There is an ArgumentError.");
}
```

`LoadVars` **example:**

```
    //create LoadVars object
    var lv_in:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
    var lv_out:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

    //set onLoad event
    lv_in.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
    {
        //if success, meaning data has received response from .net page, run this code
        if (success)
        {
        //lv_in.status is use to get the posted data from .Net page
            statusMsg.text = "Thank you!" + lv_in.status;
        }
        //if fail, run this code
        else
        {
            statusMsg.text = "Error!";
        }
    }

    //this is the data
    lv_out.data = "This is data";

    //begin invoke aspx page
    lv_out.sendAndLoad("GenerateCode.aspx", lv_in, "POST");
```

There another easier way but not the best practice i should say. The easier way would be to **direct** user to aspx page that generate dynamic code *after* users finish the flash movie. The negative side is, the page can be accessed although users did not finish the flash movie.

Comment: Thanks for the response... but I am very limited with actionscript.  Where does this code go exactly?  Is there a way to implement code onto the aspx page that will trigger a message at the end of a flash video?

Comment: Do you have the **.fla** file for the flash movie? This code goes into the flash movie as ActionScript (Open the **.fla** file movie). It is, in my opinion, better way to do what you are trying to accomplish. However, you have easier option with very minimum edit on the flash video, which I have described above also.